# Describe the region created by functions $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $y=x+1$ as type 1 or type 2 region

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let R be the region enclosed by the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and below the line $y=x+1$

Would this be neither a type 1 or type 2 region as you wouldn't be able to describe it as a type 1 or type 2 without making use of a union?

How would you describe this region as either a union of type 1 or type 2? Would the below descriptions be accurate?

Type 1: {(x,y) | -1 ≤ x ≤ 0, $-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ ≤ y ≤ x + 1 ∪ 0 ≤ x ≤ 1, $-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ ≤ y ≤ $\sqrt{1-x^2}$}

Type 2: {(x,y) | -1 ≤ y ≤ 0, $-\sqrt{1-y^2}$ ≤ x ≤ $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ ∪ 0 ≤ y ≤ 1, y - 1 ≤ x ≤ $\sqrt{1-y^2}$}

Comment: what do you mean by type 1 or type 2 region

Comment: This is part of double integration over a bounded region, type 1 being where you would integrate with respect to y first then x and in type 2, you would integrate with respect to x first then y. I'm trying to define the regions over which I would integrate.

Comment: If you draw the curves you will see that there is eally no need to integrate. The area is clear from the picture

Comment: The question forms part of a problem where I am required to calculate the double integral. I understand I can take the 3 times the quarter of a circle and the area of a triangle but that's got nothing to do with my question.